# Is short.Parse a property or a method?

Tags: c#, .net

I've used `short.Parse(somestring)` in the past. But recently I've seen a confusing usage of `short.Parse()` like below:

```
var shortArray = Array.ConvertAll(stringArr, short.Parse);
```

So, `Array.ConvertAll` expects an array and a converter. Well, fine! **But how are we passing the** `short.Parse` **as (or like) a property?** I don't find such a property in `Int16` struct. So, what is happening here actually?

Comment: `short.Parse` is a reference to the `Parse()` method group

Comment: The answer to this question might help: What is the parameter type of the second parameter?

Comment: "and a converter". And a "converter" is?

Comment: [ConvertAll source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,f4af030bcf8c8991) - one [line of code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,1045) is worth thousand words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array.ConvertAll` takes an instance of a `Converter<TIn, TOut>` delegate as its second parameter. The signature of this delegate is substantially the same as `short.Parse` - both return a value for a single argument.

The compiler will convert a 'method group' to a compatible delegate. This is known as *implicit method group conversion*.

For comparison, the *explicit* creation of the delegate would look like this:

```
Array.ConvertAll(stringArr, new Converter<string, short>(short.Parse));
```

So, to answer you question: it's still a method, not a property.  What you are doing here is passing the method as a *delegate*.  You are providing `ConvertAll` with a function to call: when it converts an element in the source array, it will execute `short.Parse(element)` and use the value returned in the new array.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about _implicit method group conversion_.I'll have a reading on it.

Answer (score 5):

`short.Parse` is a method. But it is possible to pass a method as an argument.

Note the difference between calling a method and passing the value returned by that method (`short.Parse()`), and passing the method itself (`short.Parse`).

Internally, this would be passing the address of the method so that the receiver of that argument can call it.

Comment: That's a bit of nitpicking, but `short.Parse` is not passed as the address - it is used to create a delegate of the appropriate type (can be seen in the resulting IL `newobj     instance void class [mscorlib]System.Converter2[string,int16];::.ctor(object, native int)`). No one obviously will doubt that delegates are nothing more than method addresses with optional instance reference (`this`) internally, but method group - to delegate automatic "conversion" is done by the compiler - you can't pass method group anywhere.

Comment: @EugenePodskal: So you acknowledge that internally a method address is being passed? Isn't that what I said?

Comment: I absolutely acknowledge that, but mentioning method group - to delegate conversion and that you can't pass method group anywhere will make this answer more technically correct. And it will prevent any misconceptions about method groups in those who will read it. If one reads this answer  now he may think that the method group is passed, when it is not.